# Calling Server side Methods in MVC2 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view which includes

```
<link href="<%=ScriptUrl.ToUrl("~/Content/App_Themes/Blue/Sales_Blue.css")%>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the head section of the view

I have a class as follow which is referenced in the concerned controller :

```
namespace MVCTEMP.HtmlHelpers
.....
    public class ScriptUrl
    {
        public static string ToUrl(string path)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}?v={1}", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path), MvcApplication.Version);
        }
    }
```

Why do i get The name 'ScriptUrl' does not exist in the current context when i hit run ?

any help will be appreciated
thanks
deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be

```
<link href="<%=MVCTEMP.HtmlHelpers.ScriptUrl.ToUrl("~/Content/App_Themes/Blue/Sales_Blue.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thank you but as it is common to all views in the app so i added in the web.config in the <pages><namespaces>.. <pages><namespaces> section to solve my problem .